# How to convert a file to base 64 (like .pdf,.txt) in Android?

Tags: java, android, base64

How to covert the SD-card documents (.pdf,.txt) to base 64 string and string send to the server

Comment: cab you post your codes,that you have tried.

Comment: Use this code it will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572643/3505534

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try these codes

```
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
        String encodeFileToBase64Binary = encodeFileToBase64Binary(yourFile);

        private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File fileName) throws IOException {
              byte[] bytes = loadFile(fileName);
              byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
              String encodedString = new String(encoded);
              return encodedString;
         }
```

Comment: where is `loadFile` method ?

Answer (score 8):

this method worked for me

```java
String encodeFileToBase64Binary = encodeFileToBase64Binary(yourFile);    

private String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File yourFile) {
    int size = (int) yourFile.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    try {
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourFile));
        buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return encoded;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the  meaning of the flag Base64.NO_WRAP?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is read the file to a byte array, and then use [Base64.encodeToString(byte[], int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29) to convert it to a Base64 string.