# How to convert a file to Base64?

Tags: android, base64

Here the report contain the path(pathname in sdcard in string format)

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, report);
String encodeFileToBase64Binary = encodeFileToBase64Binary(yourFile);

private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File fileName) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = loadFile(fileName);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);

    String encodedString = new String(encoded);
    return encodedString;
}
```

in the byte[] encoded line getting this error.
The method encodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64

Comment: Is your question: what should be used instead of 'encodeBase64' in Android context? Have You tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html encode() APIs?

Answer (score 19):

An updated, more efficient, Kotlin version, that bypasses Bitmaps and doesn't store entire ByteArray's in memory (risking OOM errors).

```
fun convertImageFileToBase64(imageFile: File): String {
    return ByteArrayOutputStream().use { outputStream ->
        Base64OutputStream(outputStream, Base64.DEFAULT).use { base64FilterStream ->
            imageFile.inputStream().use { inputStream ->
                inputStream.copyTo(base64FilterStream)
            }
        }
        return@use outputStream.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case Base64OutputStream truncates last several bytes, and flush() does not help. `Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)` works flawlessly. Be careful.

Comment: Is it truncating it or is it just implementing padding differently than your backend expects? See [wiki about padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Maybe it's related to padding, but it looks like a bug: result is up to 5 bytes shorter than `Base64.encodeToString()` produces and decoding back with `Base64.decode()` gives 1-2 bytes less than the original. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/gmk57/061f34cc6742c7ba16f89aa23feeaff1). I noticed this issue when Android couldn't render some JPGs after encoding/decoding.

Comment: Hmm seems like a bug. I'll raise an issue

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or intentional behaviour of `Base64OutputStream`, but this guy has [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903555/4672107). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It seems like a bug in Base64OutputStream, in that it doesn't flush it's internal buffer when `flush()` is callled, since it doesn't implement it, but it does implement `close()`

Comment: I used this one but my server is not able to decode that string

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you tried other methods and compared the string?

Answer (score 18):

```
String value = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But you can directly convert it in to String .Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 6):

I believe these 2 sample codes will help at least someone the same way many have helped me through this platform. Thanks to StackOverflow.

```
// Converting Bitmap image to Base64.encode String type
    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
}
    // Converting File to Base64.encode String type using Method
    public String getStringFile(File f) {
        InputStream inputStream = null; 
        String encodedFile= "", lastVal;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        output64.close();
        encodedFile =  output.toString();
        } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException e1 ) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        lastVal = encodedFile;
        return lastVal;
    }
```

I will be glad to answer any question regarding to these codes.

Answer (score 3):

To convert a file to Base64:

```
File imgFile = new File(filePath);
if (imgFile.exists() && imgFile.length() > 0) {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bOut);
    String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bOut.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: This code essentially reads the file to Bitmap, then compresses it again for no reason. If your file is already JPEG or PNG, it's more efficient to use my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54532684/4672107

Answer (score 1):

Convert Any file, image or video or text  into base64

1.Import the below Dependancy

```
 compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

2.Use below Code to convert file to base64

```
File file = new File(filePath);  //file Path
byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
 try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(b);
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        System.out.print((char) b[j]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] byteFileArray = new byte[0];
 try {
    byteFileArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String base64String = "";
 if (byteFileArray.length > 0) {
    base64String = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteFileArray, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
    Log.i("File Base64 string", "IMAGE PARSE ==>" + base64String);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    public static String uriToBase64(Uri uri, ContentResolver resolver, boolean thumbnail) {
        String encodedBase64 = "";
        try {
            byte[] bytes = readBytes(uri, resolver, thumbnail);
            encodedBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodedBase64;
    }
```

```js
    private static byte[] readBytes(Uri uri, ContentResolver resolver, boolean thumbnail)
            throws IOException {
        // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
        InputStream inputStream = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        if (!thumbnail) {
            // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the
            // byteBuffer
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } else {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            int thumb_width = imageBitmap.getWidth() / 2;
            int thumb_height = imageBitmap.getHeight() / 2;
            if (thumb_width > THUMBNAIL_SIZE) {
                thumb_width = THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
            }
            if (thumb_width == THUMBNAIL_SIZE) {
                thumb_height = ((imageBitmap.getHeight() / 2) * THUMBNAIL_SIZE)
                        / (imageBitmap.getWidth() / 2);
            }
            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, thumb_width, thumb_height, false);
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteBuffer);
        }
        // and then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

and call it in this way

```js
   String image = BitmapUtils.uriToBase64(Uri.fromFile(file), context.getContentResolver());
```

Comment: @UmutADALI I've updated my answer you can see the read byte function

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
...
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
base64Value = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```