# Android Studio Pdf path /document/document:15799 how to convert base64 or multipart

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, base64, multipart

In Android Studio using Pdf picker getting the path like this /document/document:15799 how to convert it to base64 or multipart or File. Or how I can get the absolute path of the pdf or docs.

```
private void selectPdf() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, true);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PDF);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);

        }
    }







@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Call..");
      if (requestCode == PDF) {
                Uri pdfUri = data.getData();

                if (!pdfUri.equals("")) {
                    
                                try {
                                
                                pdfPath = pdfUri.getPath();
                                File file = new File(pdfPath);

                                String absolutePathPdf = file.getAbsolutePath();
                            }catch (Exception ae){
                                Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+ae.toString() );
                            }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601278/how-to-convert-a-file-to-base-64-like-pdf-txt-in-android, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528094/converting-file-into-string-then-into-base64-fromate-with-android-studio

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/document:15799: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) getting this error. @AndroidGeek

Comment: `In Android Studio using Pdf picker getting the path like this /document/document:15799` That is no file system path. That is part of a content scheme. Dont use pdfUri.getPath() but pdfUri.toString() to get full content scheme. You cannot use the File class with a content scheme.

Comment: do we have any way to convert or get the absolute file path using content scheme? So I can convert that file to multipart. @blackapps

Comment: You dont need an absolute file path as you can use the uri for it. Your problem has been reported many times and been solved. Google for multipartinputstream.

Answer (score 0):

we can convert byte[] in base64 as well as in multipart too. below code works in android 11.

```
private void selectPdf() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_PDF);
    }



 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == REQ_PDF && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            try {
                Uri pdfUri = data.getData();
                frontImagePath = getPDFPath(pdfUri);
                File file = new File(frontImagePath);
                fileSize = file.length();

            }catch (Exception e){
              //  Log.d(TAG, "Exception"+e);
            }
        }

}


 public String getPDFPath(Uri uri){
        String absolutePath = "";
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            byte[] pdfInBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(pdfInBytes);
            String encodePdf = Base64.encodeToString(pdfInBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+encodePdf, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int offset = 0;
            int numRead = 0;
            while (offset < pdfInBytes.length && (numRead = inputStream.read(pdfInBytes, offset, pdfInBytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }

            String mPath = "";
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
                mPath= getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + ".pdf";
            }
            else
            {
                mPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + ".pdf";
            }

            File pdfFile = new File(mPath);
            OutputStream op = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
            op.write(pdfInBytes);

            absolutePath = pdfFile.getPath();

        }catch (Exception ae){
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        return absolutePath;
    }
```